# Expose and publish a port with specified host port number inside Dockerfile

Tags: ssh, docker

Suppose for example that I want to make an SSH host in Docker. I understand that I can `EXPOSE 22` inside `Dockerfile`. I also understand that I can use `-p 22222:22` so I can SSH into that Docker container from another physical machine on my LAN on port 22222 as `ssh my_username@docker_host_ip -p 22222:22`. But suppose that I'm so lazy that I can't be bothered to `docker run` the container with the option `-p 22222:22` every time. Is there a way that the option `-p 22222:22 can be automated in a config file somewhere? In`Dockerfile` maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

You can defind listening port in `docker-compose.yml` file as below:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: ubuntu
  ssh_service:
    build: .
    command: ssh ....
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "22222:22"
    depends_on:
      - web
```